# Find the probability that the string includes 2 consecutive elements.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

```
Four distinct digits are selected at random from the set 0, 1, 2, . . . , 9.
Find the probability that the selection includes two consecutive digits.
```

First, I found the total number of ways to select $4$ digits from the set, that is, ${\binom{10}{4}}$. Then I found the number of ways to select 4 digits from the set so that there are no consecutive integers, that is, ${\binom{7}{4}}$, and subtracted it from ${\binom{10}{4}}$.

So my answer is ${\binom{10}{4}} - {\binom{7}{4}}$ divided by ${\binom{10}{4}}$. Is this correct?

Edit: I thought the number of ways to select 4 digits from the set so that there is no consecutive element is the same as the number of ways to rearrange $AAAABBBBBB$ so that there are no consecutive $A$s. If I take the string $BBBBBB$ then I notice that there are 7 places to insert the 4 $A$s I have. The number of rearrangements is ${\binom{7}{4}}$. So the number of ways to select 4 digits so that there are no consecutive digits is ${\binom{7}{4}}$.

Comment: Indeed the number with no two consecutive is $\binom{7}{4}$. Not entirely obvious, but fairly routine Stars and Bars. If the appropriate result has not been proved in your course, a justification would be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your $AAAABBBBBB$ permutation is effectively a *selection mask* from $0123456789$.

To get a selection mask with no consecutive $A$'s, you can set up a skeleton like this: $\_\_AB\_\_AB\_\_AB\_\_A\_\_$ then add the remaining 3 $B$'s into the 5 permitted zones, which is a "stars&bars" category assignment of $5+3-1=7$ choose $3, {7\choose 3}={7\choose 4}$ consistent with your result.

Boiling down the probability into factorials, 
$$ \frac{{7\choose 3}}{{10\choose 4}}  = \frac{7!}{3!4!}\frac{6!4!}{10!} = \frac{6\times 5\times 4}{10\times 9\times 8} = \frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: how is the probability of not having any consecutive numbers the same as probability of having at least 2 consecutive digits?

Comment: @johnson ... they aren't the same; The non-consecutive case  is being used to calculate the other because they are mutually exclusive and exhaustive - every possibility is in one of the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty in this problem is to compute the number of ways to select $4$ nonconsecutive digits. The explanation why $7 \choose 4$ is the correct answer: one may notice that it's enough to choose $4$ from $7$ labeled items and then add one more after each chosen item (except for the last). This will make us sure that we have selected non consecutive digits (because there is a correspondence between the items and digits) and there are ten items/digits in total.

The description might be not clear, so here's an example. Assume that the items are letters **A, B,** C, **D,** E, F, **G.** We choose A, B, D and G, add an additional letter after A, B, D. Now we have: **A,** _, **B**, _, C, **D**, _, E, F, **G**. Ten symbols, four selected, none of them consecutive.

Comment: To compute the probability in this problem it's easier to find out what is the number of ways to select 4 nonconsecutive items, and this number is equal to $7 \choose 4$.